# Measure text length before rendering

Tags: android, textview

I have a widget where I need to display some text on one row. If the text does not fit, I would like to show as much as possible and end the text with "..." to show that not all text is displayed. Is there a way to discover how long the displayed text will be before rendering the widget, so that I can replace the last part of the text with "..."?

Cheers,

Comment: I believe the answer to this question is exactly what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666736/android-textview-automatically-truncate-and-replace-last-3-char-of-string :)

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257293/measuring-text-width-to-be-drawn-on-canvas-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do that - a TextView can do it for you.

```
myTextView.setSingleLine(true);
myTextView.setEllipsize(TextView.TruncateAt.END);
```

Comment: Damnit, it does not seem to work on widgets in pre-eclair phones. Are there any known workarounds? ;_;

Comment: I just tried it on Donut and it is doing what I expect. Are you sure there's not something else involved?