# Can I find out size in dp or px of string which I need to show on screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I find out size in dp or px of string which I need to show on screen ? What I need to do is to have one TextView with "o" sign and above centered another String with full name. I thought to use FrameLayout and set programmatically margins. Is there better way to do this ( needs to be programmatically ) ?

Comment: [Would this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3257293/593709)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the getTextSize() method to the size in pixels.