# Why for some recyclerview items, textview ellipsize check returns true during recyclerview scroll even if its false?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, ellipsize

In my `recyclerview` item, i need to check whether a textview is ellipsized or not. Based on this condition, I need to do some logic. This is my item layout xml code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_root_view"
    style="@style/ClickableRectanglePrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="13.5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="14.5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_contact_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ui_size_xl_2"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_size_xl_2"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_name"
        style="@style/activity_list_item_name_v2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text="ABC India Pvt. Ltd."
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/activity_list_item_contact_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/activity_list_item_amount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_list_item_contact_image"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_date"
        style="@style/activity_list_item_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text="Yesterday"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_list_item_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_list_item_contact_image"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_dot_text"
        style="@style/activity_list_item_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text=" \u00b7 "
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_list_item_date"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_list_item_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_status_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ui_size_xs"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_size_xs"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ui_purchase_protection_alt"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_list_item_dot_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_list_item_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_status_text"
        style="@style/activity_list_item_details"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text="Request Received"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_list_item_status_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_list_item_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/activity_list_item_amount"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_status_spillover_text"
        style="@style/activity_list_item_details"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text="Request Received"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_list_item_date"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_list_item_contact_image"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_amount"
        style="@style/UiTextView.Xl.Regular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:text="$149.99"
        android:textColor="?attr/ui_v2_color_grey_600"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/activity_list_item_contact_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The layout looks like this:
[image]

Now, I want to check whether this textview `activity_list_item_status_text` is ellipsized or not, and if it is ellipsized, show the textview in the third line `activity_list_item_status_spillover_text`. If not, hide it. I used `TreeObserver` to check this. Here's the code inside the `ViewHolder`:

```
TextView statusTextView = binding.activityListItemStatusText;
statusTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(() -> {
      Layout layout = statusTextView.getLayout();
      if (layout != null) {
           int lines = layout.getLineCount();
           if (layout.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1) > 0) {
                binding.activityListItemStatusSpilloverText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }else {
                binding.activityListItemStatusSpilloverText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
       }
 });
```

This code works fine when I open the recyclerview. But, when I scroll the recyclerview, for **some items, this condition `layout.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1) > 0` becomes true even though the text is not ellipsized and the `activity_list_item_status_spillover_text` is getting visible**. Its like text is getting ellipsized during scroll. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Is there any issue with the code?

**EDIT:**
Adding the screen recording of the problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l-xUyBJzHy-7BScsbcJPpznhwVSN7Ah4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: which method of viewholder has this code ?

Comment: I have a method called `bindDetails()` which is called from the `onBindViewHolder()` of the adapter. @rajan.kali

Comment: Can you try the same code with `statusTextView.post` after setting the text to text view.

Comment: @ADM still happening even after using `post`

Comment: Maybe calling requestLayout() before checking lines will help

Comment: @Rinat not working.

Comment: is there any way to apply `wrap-content` to textview and still be constrained to both sides?

Comment: you could try wrapping TextView with "wrap_content" inside FrameLayout/LinearLayout that is constrained on both sides. worth a shot :)

Comment: and just in case try using addOnGlobalLayoutListener instead of addOnDrawListener

Comment: @Rinat addOnGlobalLayoutListener is also not working. The problem with addOnGlobalLayoutListener is that its checking after the recycerview items are rendered. So, we sometimes we can see textviews moving, which is not a good user experience. Also, some weird things are also happening like some items are getting interchanged while scrolling when addOnGlobalLayoutListener is used.

Comment: I have added `wrap-content` and `layout_constrainedWidth="true"` to the textview and this seems to solve this particular issue. But, now i am getting another problem. Now, the items are getting interchanged while scrolling.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CWO3n4bnEazexHZayVLGouBTNDqM9uza/view?usp=sharing
Any possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. I changed the logic of finding whether the tetxview is ellipsized or not. I changed the textview code to this:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_status_text"
        style="@style/activity_list_item_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text="Request Received"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_list_item_status_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_list_item_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/activity_list_item_amount"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:maxLines="1" />
```

As you can see from the above code, I added these two lines to the code:

```
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
```

and removed `ellipsize="end"`.

Then I changed the logic to check for ellipsis to this code:

```
if (statusTextView.getLineCount() > statusTextView.getMaxLines()) {
     //Ellipsized
} else {
     //Not ellipsized
}
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `getEllipsisCount()` is not working in your case (Android is full of magic) but, instead of using it, you could compare the text in the holder against the actual text shown in the `TextView` and then, based on the result, execute your logic.

Comment: i tried. it didnt work. I printed the texts in log. The issue is while scrolling, some textviews are getting ellipsized even though the text is small. dnt know why.

Comment: What did you use to retrieve the text from the TextView? 
"some textviews are getting ellipsized even though the text is small" uhm can it be related to the width of the TextView adapting to the content? Have you tried forcing a fixed length for the TV just to understand if the ellipsis are somehow related to how the width is set?

Comment: @ Yeah. I think thats right. I think the problem is related to width of the textview. But, i have not tried anything on that route.

Comment: So the problem was the width. I don't use ConstraintLayout, but your layout doesn't seem too complicated so I'm pretty sure it can be achieved.

Comment: this problem can be solved by setting width wrap-content for the textview. But, if I give wrap-content, that textview will be not be constrained between the imageviwew and amount textview, and also it is not getting ellipsized ever. the text will be just truncated at the end. @Paolo

Comment: Ok, so the problem was related to the width. Regarding how to adapt your design I cannot help sorry, I don't use ConstraintLayout. However, the structure of the layout appears not too complicated, probably you can achieve it even with a simple LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

This is quiet common in Recycler view As it's name suggest it recycle and reuses the views and the property attained by the view are not invalidated.

Perform **viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false)** on the ViewHolder you want not to be recycled.

From docs of ViewHolder#setIsRecyclable(boolean):

Informs the recycler whether this item can be recycled. Views which are not recyclable will not be reused for other items until

> setIsRecyclable()

is later set to true.

This will cause only one **ViewHolder** to be created.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        if (holder instanceof VideoViewHolder) {
            holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        }
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        if (holder instanceof VideoViewHolder){
            holder.setIsRecyclable(true);
        }
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    }
    ...
}
```

although it would be bit taxing to make so many views in cases of long list but nevertheless this problem would be solved . as each view would have its seperate viewholder

Comment: this didnt work. I think this problem has something to do with the width of the `activity_list_item_status_text`. I have added a screen recording to the question for better understanding. And, this recording I recorded, ran the app after adding ur code in it.

Comment: well, thats strange . can we like use  diffrent viewholder and using the text in object list depending on length it will send diffrent view type one which has spillover view and one which dosent

Comment: this would add extra layer as if viewholder type is only diffrent there will be less chance of values being in wrong place

Answer (score 0):

It's because `addOnDrawListener()` will not work as intended while we scroll recycler view. `onDraw()` which is denoted by the lambda function here is asynchronous by nature, it repeatedly calls itself until the view is displayed on the screen.

Initially, function would have crashed on Scrolling down the recycler View with a **nullPointerException**, if `layout.getLines()` would have called outside `if(layout != null)` clause because textViewHolder which is responsible for creating a layout is created only once, after that it's binded and reused over and over. Due to this `textView.getLayout()` give a null at the exact moment of scrolling

> basically we are trying to call textLayout between the moments when one view is
> destroyed and another is about to be binded. this makes layout variable null for a brief period of time.

Now because layout is null when we scroll down **this part of code never really works at the moment of scrolling**, it only works after view is binded and already displayed.

```
if (layout != null) {
           int lines = layout.getLineCount();
           if (layout.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1) > 0) {
                binding.activityListItemStatusSpilloverText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }else {
                binding.activityListItemStatusSpilloverText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
       }
```

that's why it generates anomalies at certain places once scroll down or up the recycler View. The best way would be to use a non-lifecycle-dependent way of defining if the textview is ellispize or not.

you can also reffer this [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener), which in the end says

> Callback method to be invoked when the view tree is about to be drawn. At this point, views cannot be modified in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can avoid using tree observer.

Instead inside view holder you can measure text width.

Using textview paint and these answers [Measuring text width to be drawn on Canvas ( Android )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257293/measuring-text-width-to-be-drawn-on-canvas-android)

If text width exceeds textview width, this means textview will be ellipsized.

Comment: The reason for using Tree observer is to do everything before rendering the items. If i didn't use it, the user will clearly see the textviews hiding and unhiding, which is not a good user experience.